# Windows cannot detect the Galaxy S I9000 when connected through USB

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, usb-connection-mode

When I connect my Galaxy SI900 with the PC, I get the message, "A USB device connected cannot be recognised". I reinstalled drivers on the PC and it resintalled Kies. Thses didn't resolve the problem. Any suggestions.

Comment: Have you restarted your phone? I recall having a similar problem with my Samsung Fascinate and I ended up fixing it by rebooting the phone.

Comment: Make sure, you are connected with Internet while connecting the device... Windows Update can help.. I'm not sure Windows Update needs to be turn on or not, to search drivers..

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with Kies. Latest version of Kies and latest USB drivers solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a damaged usb cable, low quality cable, or one that's too long can cause this as well. So perhaps make sure you're using the original cable that came with the device.
Also if you're using a usb hub with a desktop computer try plugging the cable directly into the computer instead.